# How to use "auth" with Adonis without a crypted password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, adonis.js

I using Adonis connect with a MSSQL DB who doesn't own a crypted password, but a i need to generate a token to reuse (because that i using Auth) but it does not work.

reading the [documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/encryption-and-hashing#_hashing_values), i try to "Hash" that password and them auth, did not work. So i try, encrypt and them auth, nope again.

And finally i try to crypt, hash and them Auth... And them not work :|

Someone how get pass for this, can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible without encrypted password. Keeping passwords unencrypted is not a good idea.

You can encrypt all password with this code :

```js
  const Hash = use("Hash");

  const users = await User.all();
  users.rows.forEach(async u => {
    u.password = await Hash.make(u.password);
    await u.save();
  });
```

*!! Only run one time*

Comment: I agree, I don't like this idea either, but as I can't decrypt the password generated by GeneXus (TwoFish Cryptography), this is the solution that I have left ... Although what I would like most is a way to be able to use "Auth "

Comment: Okay, I looked at the `Auth` source code, and it's necessary to hash the passwords. One solution : (I didn't test) You can create a user hook https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/database-hooks#_lifecycle_events `afterFind` or `afterFetch` (try both). In this hook just Hash the password field `user.password = await Hash.make(user.password);`